# Page Displaying different in IE but OK in FF and Chrome

Tags: css

Can anybody help me with this CSS issue. This online tutorial displays ok in FF and Chrome but in IE, the  main content is pushed down the page for some reason.

Here's the link:
[Problem Page](http://hanlonthesis.com/lesson1_webdev.php)

GF

Answer (score 0):

In your 1.css file:

change the width to 100%:

```
#content {
    TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN: 0px; WIDTH: 100%; FONT-FAMILY: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Verdana
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was something I should have spotted myself.